# Request enviando json

Tags: python, http-request

Estou tentando fazer uma request pelo python.
Segue o que tentei:

```
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/detection/'
    headers = {'charset': 'utf-8'}
    response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
```

Já chequei varias vezes, o que chega pelo data, está correto. Tentei chamar a rota pelo postman também, e vai perfeitamente. Cheguei a copiar e colar o json que envio, e está correto. Porém, quando chamo a rota pelo python, retorna o erro 400

Comment: Coloca um exemplo de como esta montando esse `data` no python antes de enviar por favor

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma diferença entre usar o parâmetro `json` e o parâmetro `data`, talvez você esteja confundindo os dois.

Numa requisição POST, são enviados os headers e o "corpo" da mensagem. No caso do uso de `json` ou `data`, o corpo nada mais é do que uma string; acontece que é uma string enviada em formato diferente pra um ou pra outro.

No caso do parâmetro `data`, é enviado como um formulário (como se fosse seu navegador após clicar "enviar") e um header indicando que o conteúdo do corpo é do formato `x-www-form-urlencoded` é adicionado automaticamente:

```
In [9]: r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/anything', data={'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 1337})

In [10]: r.request.body
Out[10]: 'foo=bar&baz=1337'

In [11]: r.request.headers['Content-Type']
Out[11]: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Quando você usa o parâmetro `json`, o `requests` automaticamente transforma o seu corpo em JSON e adiciona um header indicando que o conteúdo do corpo é do tipo `JSON`:

```
In [13]: r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/anything', json={'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 1337})

In [14]: r.request.body
Out[14]: b'{"foo": "bar", "baz": 1337}'

In [15]: r.request.headers['Content-Type']
Out[15]: 'application/json'
```

Qual dos dois você vai usar vai depender do formato que a API aceita, mas tenha em mente essas diferenças.